# adding dynamic image in ajax laravel path error not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, laravel-5.4

i have a `<div class="uploaded-images">` where i want to put all my images that came from my ajax dynamically. I am having error 404 in my code by looping my ajax data result to append in my `div`, i am having trouble in getting the path of my image because i am a beginner in using laravel 5.4

Here is my code:

```
function getProductDetails(product_id) {
    $( ".uploaded-images" ).empty();
    $.ajax({         
        url: "{{ url('user/get-showproduct') }}/" +product_id,        
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

            for(var i=0;i<data.product_images.length;i++) {
                 $(".uploaded-images").append('<li><img src="{{asset('image_files')}}/"+data.product_images[i].product_image"/></li>');
            };
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `console.log(data.product_images);` please ? And the URL you get in the src when the loop is done, that would be helpful.

Comment: product_images [3]
0 Object
product_image DSC04477-e1490885078524-200x300.jpg
1 Object
product_image galaxy-s8-200.jpg
2 Object
product_image -s8-plus-200.jpg

Comment: @teeyo thanks for your reply i think my error is in this line
$(".uploaded-images").append('<li><img src="{{asset('image_files')}}/"+data.product_images[i].product_image"/></li>');

Comment: Yup, this URL `image_files/DSC04477-e1490885078524-200x300.jpg` should be accessible

Comment: @teeyo thanks for your reply sir. it says error 404

Comment: And do you have that image in the image_files folder ? can you verify that ? I mean the data you're getting is correct the problem is in the way you are creating that URL!

Comment: @teeyo yes sir i have it